# Strain between two rotated lattices

Tags: crystals, stress-strain

I want to calculate what I believe is called the "Deformation gradient tensor" $\mathbf{F}$ between two crystal lattices.

The matrix representation of the first 'perfect' i.e., not deformed lattice is $\mathbf{A}$. The transformation to the second lattice matrix representation $\mathbf{A'}$ of the deformed (strain + shear) lattice should then be:

$$\mathbf{FA} = \mathbf{A'}$$

But my problem is that these two lattices are randomly rotated (well only the second one actually), how would one proceed to separate strain + shear from rotation? I tried to build $\mathbf{F}$ by playing with the lengths and angles of both lattices as they are rotation invariant. But I lost myself with the cosines and sines... Is there a simpler way to do what I want?

Comment: What does the matrix representation of a lattice mean?  Can you give an example?

Comment: @ChetMiller The matrix representation of a lattice is 3 vectors that define the lattice, this can be cubic (only diagonal elements are non-zero) or anything else really. First matrix row is the first vector etc...